# Mobile Safari / Safari fixed position not repainting

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari, repaint

I have a page with a menu hidden behind the main page content. On clicking a button the content (`#container`) slides to the left revealing the menu.

```
  <div id="container">
    <button onclick="toggleNavState()">NAV TOGGLE</button>

    <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
  </div>

  <div id="side_nav">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="xxxxx">xxxxxxxxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="xxxxx">xxxxxxxxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="xxxxx">xxxxxxxxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="xxxxx">xxxxxxxxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="xxxxx">xxxxxxxxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="xxxxx">xxxxxxxxx</a></li>
      </ul>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleNavState() {
            elem = document.getElementById("container"); 
            var className1 = 'active';
            var className2 = 'inactive';
            elem.className = (elem.className == className1)?className2:className1;

        }
```

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 520px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
  background: #FFF;
}

#container.active {
  right: 250px;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I've used this technique on a few sites and it works just fine. The problem arrises when I try to add a fixed footer.

The footer should stay fixed within `#container` as it slides to the left and it does in all browsers I've tested except Mobile Safari and Safari.

If there is a `block` level element within `#container` the footer appears to instead be positioned relative to the viewport. It works fine if the `block` element is removed.

**Without block element:**

[image: Footer correctly positioned]

**With block element:**

[image: Footer incorrectly positioned]

I suspect this is a re-painting issue as when the screen is scrolled to the bottom (MobileSafari) or resized (Safari) the footer snaps back into it's correct position within `#container`.

Furthermore, forcing a redraw with [Mr. Darcy Murphy's](http://mrdarcymurphy.tumblr.com/post/5574489334/force-mobile-safari-to-repaint-redraw) technique also causes the footer to snap back into it's correct position.

The following examples are only relevant if viewing in Safari. You won't see the problem in other browsers.

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/ebujuz/5/)

[NON-WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/ebujuz/3/)

**Could anyone shed any light on why this happening?**

Answer (score 0):

Landed here trying to find an answer for similar behavior using `position: absolute` on mobile (works on Desktop).

> I suspect this is a re-painting issue as when the screen is scrolled to the bottom (MobileSafari) or resized (Safari) the footer snaps back into it's correct position

Yes, many other actions that trigger a re-paint fix the problem for me too. For example:

- turning on/off a CSS class on the dev tools
- resizing the dev tools

Use `translateZ(0)` to work around the problem, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27971913/7852

Answer (score -2):

it worked for me when I changed that fixed position to absolute position.

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: But then it won't be fixed to the bottom of the screen. #container can be much longer than the screen in reality

Comment: i suggest adding some treatment for `footer` with some javascript to make it `right: 250px;` when you reveal the nav