# Item Slider jQuery can't find out how to add more items in one line and add another slider for them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery http://bit.ly/NQ4YgQ and I need add more items to the slider. Ideal is if I can make them slide too like from left to right so I can add more items to the category and have these items in one line and can list in them with another slider.

I have it applied on this page:

```
http://phantommma.zdenekriha.eu/kolekce.php
```

Only thing I find out was in

```
.mi-slider ul li
```

where I findout that decreasing width will help to have all the items in one line. I tried to add http://bit.ly/NQ5Dii this slideshow on the `<ul>` of the items list but it wasn't working together too well..

THE CODE:

PAGE

```
<div class="main">
                <div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img01"><h4>Boots</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img02"><h4>Oxfords</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="img03"><h4>Loafers</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="img04"><h4>Sneakers</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05"><h4>Belts</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="img06"><h4>Hats &amp; Caps</h4></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05"><h4>Belts</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="img06"><h4>Hats &amp; Caps</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="img07"><h4>Sunglasses</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="img08"><h4>Scarves</h4></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/9.jpg" alt="img09"><h4>Casual</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/10.jpg" alt="img10"><h4>Luxury</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/11.jpg" alt="img11"><h4>Sport</h4></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/12.jpg" alt="img12"><h4>Carry-Ons</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/13.jpg" alt="img13"><h4>Duffel Bags</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/14.jpg" alt="img14"><h4>Laptop Bags</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/15.jpg" alt="img15"><h4>Briefcases</h4></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <nav>
                        <a href="#">Shoes</a>
                        <a href="#">Accessories</a>
                        <a href="#">Watches</a>
                        <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
                        </div>


                    <script>
                            $(function() {

                                $( '#mi-slider' ).catslider();

                            });
                    </script>
```

THE SCRIPT OF CATEGORIES

```
    ;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

    'use strict';

    $.CatSlider = function( options, element ) {
        this.$el = $( element );
        this._init( options );
    };

    $.CatSlider.prototype = {

        _init : function( options ) {

            // the categories (ul)
            this.$categories = this.$el.children( 'ul' );
            // the navigation
            this.$navcategories = this.$el.find( 'nav > a' );
            var animEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
                'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
                'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
                'animation' : 'animationend'
            };
            // animation end event name
            this.animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ];
            // animations and transforms support
            this.support = Modernizr.csstransforms && Modernizr.cssanimations;
            // if currently animating
            this.isAnimating = false;
            // current category
            this.current = 0;
            var $currcat = this.$categories.eq( 0 );
            if( !this.support ) {
                this.$categories.hide();
                $currcat.show();
            }
            else {
                $currcat.addClass( 'mi-current' );
            }
            // current nav category
            this.$navcategories.eq( 0 ).addClass( 'mi-selected' );
            // initialize the events
            this._initEvents();

        },
        _initEvents : function() {

            var self = this;
            this.$navcategories.on( 'click.catslider', function() {
                self.showCategory( $( this ).index() );
                return false;
            } );

            // reset on window resize..
            $( window ).on( 'resize', function() {
                self.$categories.removeClass().eq( 0 ).addClass( 'mi-current' );
                self.$navcategories.eq( self.current ).removeClass( 'mi-selected' ).end().eq( 0 ).addClass( 'mi-selected' );
                self.current = 0;
            } );

        },
        showCategory : function( catidx ) {

            if( catidx === this.current || this.isAnimating ) {
                return false;
            }
            this.isAnimating = true;
            // update selected navigation
            this.$navcategories.eq( this.current ).removeClass( 'mi-selected' ).end().eq( catidx ).addClass( 'mi-selected' );

            var dir = catidx > this.current ? 'right' : 'left',
                toClass = dir === 'right' ? 'mi-moveToLeft' : 'mi-moveToRight',
                fromClass = dir === 'right' ? 'mi-moveFromRight' : 'mi-moveFromLeft',
                // current category
                $currcat = this.$categories.eq( this.current ),
                // new category
                $newcat = this.$categories.eq( catidx ),
                $newcatchild = $newcat.children(),
                lastEnter = dir === 'right' ? $newcatchild.length - 1 : 0,
                self = this;

            if( this.support ) {

                $currcat.removeClass().addClass( toClass );

                setTimeout( function() {

                    $newcat.removeClass().addClass( fromClass );
                    $newcatchild.eq( lastEnter ).on( self.animEndEventName, function() {

                        $( this ).off( self.animEndEventName );
                        $newcat.addClass( 'mi-current' );
                        self.current = catidx;
                        var $this = $( this );
                        // solve chrome bug
                        self.forceRedraw( $this.get(0) );
                        self.isAnimating = false;

                    } );

                }, $newcatchild.length * 90 );

            }
            else {

                $currcat.hide();
                $newcat.show();
                this.current = catidx;
                this.isAnimating = false;

            }

        },
        // based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/8840703/989439
        forceRedraw : function(element) {
            if (!element) { return; }
            var n = document.createTextNode(' '),
                position = element.style.position;
            element.appendChild(n);
            element.style.position = 'relative';
            setTimeout(function(){
                element.style.position = position;
                n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
            }, 25);
        }

    }

    $.fn.catslider = function( options ) {
        var instance = $.data( this, 'catslider' );
        if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
            this.each(function() {
                instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
            });
        }
        else {
            this.each(function() {
                instance ? instance._init() : instance = $.data( this, 'catslider', new $.CatSlider( options, this ) );
            });
        }
        return instance;
    };

} )( jQuery, window );
```

THE CSS OF SCRIPT

```
    .mi-slider {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 80px;
    height: 490px;
}

.mi-slider ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.no-js .mi-slider ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-current {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.mi-slider ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 300px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(600%);
    transform: translateX(600%);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.no-js .mi-slider ul li {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.mi-slider ul li a,
.mi-slider ul li img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mi-slider ul li a {
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mi-slider ul li img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: none;
}

.mi-slider ul li h4 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Baskerville, "Baskerville Old Face", "Hoefler Text", Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 10px 0;
}

.mi-slider ul li:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
} 

.mi-slider nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 5px solid #333;
}

.no-js nav {
    display: none;
}

.mi-slider nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 40px 30px 30px 34px;
    position: relative;
    color: #888;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
    transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.mi-slider nav a:hover,
.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected {
    color: #000;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:after,
.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    border: solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:after {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-width: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:before {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: #333;
    border-width: 27px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -27px;
}

/* Move classes and animations */

.mi-slider ul:first-child li,
.no-js .mi-slider ul li {
    -webkit-animation: scaleUp 350ms ease-in-out both;
    animation: scaleUp 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleUp {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0) scale(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0) scale(1); }
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
    0% { transform: translateX(0) scale(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0) scale(1); }
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:first-child {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 90ms;
    animation-delay: 90ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 180ms;
    animation-delay: 180ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 270ms;
    animation-delay: 270ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 360ms;
    animation-delay: 360ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 450ms;
    animation-delay: 450ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 540ms;
    animation-delay: 540ms;
}

/* moveFromRight */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li {
    -webkit-animation: moveFromRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
    animation: moveFromRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* moveFromLeft */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li {
    -webkit-animation: moveFromLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
    animation: moveFromLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* moveToRight */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li {
    -webkit-animation: moveToRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
    animation: moveToRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* moveToLeft */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li {
    -webkit-animation: moveToLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
    animation: moveToLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* Animation Delays */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:first-child,
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:first-child,
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(6),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0ms;
    animation-delay: 0ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(2),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(2),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(3),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 90ms;
    animation-delay: 90ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(3),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(3),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(2),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 180ms;
    animation-delay: 180ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(5),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(5),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(4),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(4)  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 270ms;
    animation-delay: 270ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(6),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(6),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(5),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(5)  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 360ms;
    animation-delay: 360ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(6),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(6),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:first-child,
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:first-child  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 450ms;
    animation-delay: 450ms;
}

/* Animations */

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromRight {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(600%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromLeft {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-600%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToRight {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(600%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToLeft {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-600%); }
}

@keyframes moveFromRight {
    0% { transform: translateX(600%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}

@keyframes moveFromLeft {
    0% { transform: translateX(-600%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}

@keyframes moveToRight {
    0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(600%); }
}

@keyframes moveToLeft {
    0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-600%); }
}

.mi-slider {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 910px){
    .mi-slider nav {
        max-width: 90%;
    }
    .mi-slider nav a {
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 40px 10px 30px 14px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
    .mi-slider {
        height: 300px;
    }
    .mi-slider nav {
        top: 220px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 490px){ 
    .mi-slider {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
    }

    .mi-slider ul {
        position: relative;
        display: inline;
        bottom: auto;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .mi-slider ul li {
        -webkit-animation: none !important;
        animation: none !important;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
        transform: translateX(0) !important;
        padding: 10px 3px;
        min-width: 140px;
    }

    .mi-slider nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Will be happy for any hint or solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to provide relevant code in question. No one like to have to go here or there to debug someone else website, would you like it?

Comment: The code would be really long so I thought this will be easier. But OK  I will post it.

Comment: The relevant code shouldn't be that long. I'm not asking you to post ALL your website's code. You have to post the minimalistic sample code which reproduces your issue.

Comment: Updated Added the CSS of the script, the script and the HTML for the script. Tried to make it in jsfiddle but not working there.

Comment: friend,put appropriate code for what you want..Don't put the complete code,no one will go through your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I think its as easy as finding the

```
ul .mi-current
```

and then just adding new

```
<li></li>
```

Comment: No this is not the problem. But thanks for the answer.