# when the dynamic stylesheets is applied?

Tags: javascript, css

I load some style.css dynamically in javascript. when the style is loaded, I'll do some calculation that depends on the styles. The code is like this:

```
link = document.createElement('link');
link.href = 'sheety.css';
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.head.appendChild(link);
link.onload = function(){
    //some code
    //here, I can't the the correct style sometime.
    //but most of the time, I can get the correct style
    setTimeout(function(){
        //here, I can also get the correct style
    }, 1000);
};
```

So, my question is: when does the style is applied successfully?
If I modify the element's position(width, height), can I get the correct value instant, or I must wait some time to let the browser do something by using like `setTimeout()` function?

---

I read some resources that says: call `dom.getComputedStyle` will cause a browser reflow.
I indeed call this method, but I still get the wrong width/height of the DOM.

When I debug the JS code in chrome, I can see that the style is not applied at the break point (from the style tab in chrome developer tools).

Answer (score 0):

Once the style sheet is loaded, a CSSOM or [CSSObjectModel](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/) is generated. Along with the DOM, the CSSOM is rasterized by a rasterizer and applied (in Chrome, done by [Skia](https://code.google.com/p/skia/)).

A style can be said to be applied successfully when a browser completes a reflow or a repaint. We can force the browser for a redraw using many techniques:

1. element.hide().show(); #using jQuery
2. Inserting a node into the DOM
   and removing it.

These techniques are better explained in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac).