# JavaScript innerHTML Quirk - Disappearing Elements..

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have a UI bug thingy that I cannot solve for the life of me..

I have a bunch of `<div>`'s with id's that are part of my index page. I have a list of links that pass a JSON through a `onclick` function, that replaces these elements text..

I have tried to use `innerHTML` and `textContent` - Now both work great, expect for when one of the functions needs to pull additional information from the database...when this happens it it making my other elements disappear. Now their HTML is still there and their inner content, but it is not displaying the values - other borders and text are disappearing too...they will only reappear when I resize the window and they seem to pop back up..

I should point out this is only happening in Chrome and Safari - Firefox and IE works just fine..

I am stumped on this one, any help would be killer!!

Code..

```
<p class="restaurant-name" id="restaurant-name"></p>

var emptyName = document.getElementById('restaurant-name');
emptyName.textContent = restInfo.name;
```

restInfo is the name of the JSON

Comment: If the problem only happens when you're fetching additional info from the database, could you post the code related to that?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or a little more code to simulate the problem?

Comment: Possibly force a redraw after loading new content. Just a thought... [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac)

Comment: This is what I thought it was: http://www.eccesignum.org/blog/solving-display-refreshredrawrepaint-issues-in-webkit-browsers  But I still cannot figure this out for the life of me!