# Casper.js / Phantom.js - possible to re-evaluate CSS from injected <style> tags?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

My web app works by injecting
`<style>.some_selector {width: 12345px;}</style>`
tags before the closing `<body>` tag.

This works fine in the browser but when using

`casper.capture()`

I notice that the injected styles are not implemented. Is there any way I can tell Casper to re-evaluate the DOM?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac) inside of a `casper.evaluate` should work. Do you have an example link, where I could test some things out? Usually this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It's part of a really big app that's not sitting on a public url unfortunately, I guess i'l keep blindly trying things!

Comment: You could add `body { zoom: 1; }` to the style that you inject, maybe it works.