# element won't appear until resize (Safari browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have an element with class btn-getInfo-Ok

```
<button class="btn-getInfo-Ok">Hello</button>
```

style.css

```css
.btn-getInfo-Ok {
  color:white !important;
  margin: 0  auto !important;
  height:50px;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

The button appears perfectly on chrome, but when I run it on Safari, the button doesn't appear until I resize the window. I also noticed that if I remove

```
bottom:0
```

from the btn-getInfo-Ok class, the issue doesn't happen on either browsers.

Please help

I have tried $('window').resize() which doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me:

```
$('#parentOfElementToBeRedrawn').hide().show(0);
```

[Force DOM redraw/refresh on Chrome/Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac)