# AngularJS - CSS animations are only working one way

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to animate an element from `height: 20px` to `height: 0`, but its not working. However, a transition from 0 to 20 does work. I'm using angular to add/remove items from an array:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctl', ctl);

ctl.$inject = ['$timeout'];

function ctl($timeout) {
  var self = this;

  self.newItemText = '';
  self.deleteItem = function(id) {
    self.items[id].class = 'hidden';
  };
  self.addItem = function() {
    var newItem = {
      id: self.items.length,
      class: 'hidden',
      text: self.newItemText
    };
    self.items.push(newItem);
    self.items[self.items.length - 1].class = 'visible';
    self.newItemText = '';
  }

  self.items = [{
    id: 0,
    class: 'visible',
    text: 'one'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    class: 'visible',
    text: 'two'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    class: 'visible',
    text: 'three'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    class: 'visible',
    text: 'one'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    class: 'visible',
    text: 'two'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    class: 'visible',
    text: 'three'
  }, {
    id: 6,
    class: 'visible',
    text: 'one'
  }, {
    id: 7,
    class: 'visible',
    text: 'two'
  }, {
    id: 8,
    class: 'visible',
    text: 'three'
  }, ];
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
}
.close {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.visible {
  height: 20px;
  transition: height 0.2s linear;
}
.hidden {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctl as c'>
  <input ng-model='c.newItemText' />
  <button ng-click='c.addItem()'>
    add
  </button>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='item in c.items' class='{{item.class}}'>
        <span class='text'>{{item.text}}</span>
        <span class='close' ng-click='c.deleteItem(item.id)'>x</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

relevant css:

```
.visible {
  height: 20px;
  transition: height 0.2s linear;
}
.hidden {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.2s linear;
}
```

full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/1rqhLo83/

Comment: Try adding `overflow: auto` to the `.visible` class. to counteract the `overflow: hidden` on the `.hidden` class. -- but in reality.. I'm wondering if you are expecting the new items to transition. Since they aren't *already* part of the DOM, I don't think they'll transition via CSS.

Comment: @SOIA tried it, didn't do anything

Comment: I think you may have written this question a bit backwards -- 20  to 0 works. 0 to 20 does not.... but see my previous comment.

Comment: @SOIA I think they're part of the dom, they just have 0 height at first, then I update their height (see the angular code)

Comment: It's because your element's height is already on `20px`. Have you tried using css `keyframes`?

Comment: @LekzFlores no I haven't, but how is the height already on 20? try to comment out the code in the add function in the angular controller where the class is updated. the li won't appear.

Comment: Inside your `JS` code. As soon as you add `items` and set its class as `visible`, is it you already set its height to `20px`? Btw, using `keyframes` https://jsfiddle.net/1rqhLo83/1/. Just need a little fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the order in which the events occur:

- The element is appended with a class of `hidden`
- The class is subsequently changed to `visible`
- Then a [reflow/paint event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac) occurs and the CSS is updated visually

In doing so, you aren't seeing the transition when the element is initially appended because the repaint event doesn't occur until the class is already `visible`.

One solution is to append the element with both classes and then remove the `visible` class after a slight 10ms timeout. In doing so, a reflow event will occur and the transition will take effect as expected.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/20d82tgt/)

```
self.addItem = function() {
    var newItem = {
    id: self.items.length,
    class: 'visible hidden',
    text: self.newItemText
  };
  self.items.push(newItem);
  $timeout(function () {
    self.items[self.items.length - 1].class = 'visible';
  }, 10);
  self.newItemText = '';
}
```

Then modify your CSS to the following:

```
.visible {
  height: 20px;
  transition: height 1s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hidden {
  height: 0;
}
```