# Jquery animation mouse cursor not and style not changed after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, animation

I am using JQuery animation ,I am facing issue on chrome.

As per requirement I need to animate the div on click of a link.

when cursor moved hover link, link should be underlined and cursor should show as pointer but even after clicking on link even after animation if user not moved mouse mouse pointer not get changed and link also shows underlined. if users moves mouse it works fine.

fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/pratiknvyas/wsaqfcxj/

Where on other browsers it works fine.

Comment: May be I get you wrong, but in my environment your fiddle works identical at Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: To reproduce just click on link don't move mouse you can see still link is underlined and cursor as pointed in chrome while in ff after animation link display without underlined and default cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.hide().show(0)` for animate element for compensate Chrome bug.

Please, take a look at [feedle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsaqfcxj/10/).

Related:
[How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3485365/1056384)
[Force DOM redraw/refresh on Chrome/Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8840580/1056384)