# How to ensure that a function containing multiple $.ajax calls runs fully synchronously and also allows for browser repaints as it executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I've been working on getting a function written to:

1) Process an input array using $.ajax calls to fill an output array (below this is inputList)

2) Below is what I have, but I'm having issues with it:

- requestData(), when I call it, runs straight through to processing the outputList array without having fully populated/filled it - it puts one value into it then starts to process that, but the function still apparently runs on seperately to the subsequent processing asynchronously. I need it to be fully synchronous so that it does not return until the inputList array has been fully processed.
- I'm not seeing the browser repainting the div that has its html updated on every call of the runajax() function - I'm attempting to do this with a setTimeout.

3) I've set the ajax request to be synchronous (async : false) - but this doesn't seem to help

I've tried to use jQuery's $.when to provide an ability to ensure that everything gets called in sequence - but clearly I'm not doing this correctly.

Would appreciate any help - I've asked previous related questions around this and had some useful help - but I've still not resolved this!

Thanks

```
//declare holding function requestData - expects a non-empty input data array named inputList
    function requestData() {

//declare inner function runajax
        function runajax() {

            if(inputList.length > 0) {
//get first item from inputlist and shorten inputList
                var data = $.trim(inputList.shift());

                function getData() {
//send the data to server
                    return $.ajax({
                        url: 'sada_ajax_fetch_data.php',
                        cache: false,
                        async: false,
                        method: "post",
                        timeout: 2000,
                        data: {
                            requesttype: "getmydata",
                            email: encodeURIComponent(data)
                         }
                    });
                }

                function handleReturnedData (response) {
                    response = $.trim(decodeURIComponent(response));
//update the div inner html
                    if(response == "Failed") {
                        $('#fetchupdatestatus').html('There was an error retrieving the data you requested!'); 
                    } else {
                        $('#fetchupdatestatus').html('The item returned was '+response);                    
                    }

//add the response from ajax to the end of the outputList array
                    outputList.push(response);
//set up the next ajax call
                    var doNextBitOfWork = function () {
                        runajax();
                    };
//call setTimeout so that browser shows refreshed div html
                    setTimeout(doNextBitOfWork, 0);
//return
                    return $.when();
                }

//do the next ajax request and response processing
                return getData().done(handleReturnedData);

            } else {
//did the last one so return
                return $.when();
            }
        }
//kick off the ajax calls
        runajax();
    }

    var inputList = new Array();
    var outputList = new Array();

    .....load +/- 100 values to be processed using ajax into array inputList

    requestData();

    .....process stuff in array outputList
    .....etc
```

Answer (score 0):

There was my answer with "you're doing it wrong" earlier, but then I just decided to show, how you can do it (almost) right: https://jsfiddle.net/h4ffz1by/

```
var request_maker = {
  working: false,
  queue: [],
  output: [],
  requestData: function(inputList) {
    if (request_maker.working == true) {
      return false;
    }
    request_maker.output = [];
    request_maker.working = true;
    while (inputList.length > 0) {
      var data = $.trim(inputList.shift());
      request_maker.queue.push(data);
    }
    console.log(request_maker.queue);
    request_maker.doTheJob();
    return true;
  },

  doTheJob: function() {
    current_data_to_send = request_maker.queue.shift();
    console.log(current_data_to_send);

    if (typeof current_data_to_send != 'undefined' && request_maker.queue.length >= 0) {


      $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        cache: false,
        method: "post",
        timeout: 2000,
        data: {
          requesttype: "getmydata",
          email: encodeURIComponent(current_data_to_send)
        },
        success: function(data, status, xhrobject) {
          console.log(xhrobject);
          request_maker.handleReturnedData(data);

        },
      });
    } else {
      request_maker.working = false;
      console.log('all data has been sent');
    }
  },
  handleReturnedData: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    response = $.trim(decodeURIComponent(response));
    //response= 'Failed';//uncomment to emulate this kind of response
    if (response == "Failed") {
      $('#fetchupdatestatus').append('There was an error retrieving the data you requested!<br/>');
    } else {
      $('#fetchupdatestatus').append('The item returned was ' + response + '<br/>');
      request_maker.output.push(response);
    }
    request_maker.doTheJob();
    if (request_maker.working == false) {
      console.log('all requests have been completed');
      console.log(request_maker.output);
    }
  }
}

inputList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
if (request_maker.requestData(inputList)) {
  console.log('started working');
}

if (!request_maker.requestData(inputList)) {
  console.log('work in progress, try again later');
}
```

Note that I've changed request path to jsfiddle's ajax simulation link and replaced `html()` with `append()` calls to print text in div. The calls are made and get handled in the same order as it is in `inputList`, still they don't lock user's browser. `request_maker.output`'s elements order is also the same as in `inputList`.

Have in mind, that you will need to add `error` handling too (probably just a function that pushes 'error' string into `output` instead of result), otherwise any ajax error (403/404/502, etc.) will get it "stuck" in `working` state. Or you can use `complete` instead of `success` and check request status right there.

**UPD:** Answer to the question: you cannot get both. You either use callbacks and let browser repaint inbetween asynchroneous requests or you make requests synchroneous and block browser untill your code finished working.

**UPD2:** There actually is some information on forcing redraw, however I don't know if it will work for you: [Force DOM redraw/refresh on Chrome/Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac)

Comment: Thanks @haldagan - I'll give this a try!

Comment: -moved this to answer post-

Comment: this works great in terms of the browser repaint BUT the problem I still have is that I need to ensure that the script that contains this doesn't proceed UNTIL all processing has been completed - and we have the output in place. IE: if I put e.g. console.log("we reached here because everything has been processed and output is ready for further processing"); right after your last "}" in above, then I don't want to see that until we're 100% done?

Comment: ..cont: Right now if I add that to your fiddle, then I see it right after "stated working", obviously. I don't want to have to encapsulate all my following code in a callback, as it is complex and staggered. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not really sure of why will you need this, yet you can add `async:false` to ajax request, but then you will need to get rid of `working` flag and all checks with it as long as it will have no use anymore. Note, that requests/data will be sent/recieved synchroneously, yet the page will be re-rendered only at the end and not as soon as data is recieved (at least in chrome). You need to choose, what do you want more - "simplicity" of the code, or the code working as you've planned. You can not actually make interpreter `sleep` to let browser render page - you'll need callbacks either way.

Comment: P.S.: I'm wondering why were you using `when`in the first place as it just provides callbacks for asynchroneous events (especially if you don't want it to be asynchroneous and don't want to use callbacks).

Comment: I've updated my answer to actually answer your question.