# workaround for display block and css transitions not triggering

Tags: javascript, css, repaint

**Sorry all for so many updates in this question and I'm glad for everyone trying to help me. I think below there is a more clear way to understand this problem:**

CSS transitions will not apply if you set the display property of an element to block immediately before changing the property with the transition attached. Consider the following code:

CSS:

```
#creative {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="creative">
    <span>Sample text</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var dom = {};
dom.creative = document.getElementById('creative');
dom.creative.style.display = 'block';
dom.creative.style.opacity = 1;
```

The element will properly show, but without any transition. A workaround for this problem is to force a repaint by accessing one of the visual properties of the element:

```
dom.creative.style.display = 'block';
var a = dom.creative.offsetHeight; /* <-- forces repaint */
dom.creative.style.opacity = 1;
```

is there a good way around this? and by good i mean not adding a extra line of javascript code everytime i need to change the display property and a property with a transition attached.

Comment: Very good question! I am curious about this too, and will dig to see what I find...

Comment: transition works where numbers are involved ... it goes step by steps, but not with states like none/block where ... you actually have a single step :)  (beside how to apply opacity  on display:none element )

Comment: Consider changing your question to define objective criteria of what you expect to see in an answer. Right now it appears you're asking for opinions ("best" "more elegant"), which are generally off-topic.

Comment: It seems like only hacks exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365, and comprehensive list by Paul Irish: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Comment: Do you want to repaint or do you want a transition/animation to be re-executed?

Comment: @LGSon english is not my first language so i'm sorry for not being clear. I'm looking for a good way to trigger a repaint after setting the display to block and before setting the opacity to 1.

Comment: Not mine either (English) ... are we talking about the transition or just to repaint an element of any kind?

Comment: The repaint is needed because after the display is set to block the transition will not apply without a repaint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you present in your question I'm going on a completely different way here, and use `animation` instead, which will make the whole *repaint* issue go away

*Updated with a script the set the div to `display: block`*

```js
var dom = {};
dom.creative = document.getElementById('creative');
dom.creative.style.display = 'none';

var butt = document.getElementById('button');
butt.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
  if (dom.creative.style.display == 'block') {
    dom.creative.style.display = 'none';    
  } else {
    dom.creative.style.display = 'block';
  }

})
```

```css
#creative {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: opac 1s forwards;
  margin: 20px;
}
@keyframes opac {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
button {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Toggle display</button>

<div id="creative">
  <span>Sample text</span>
</div>
```

*If `display: none` is not needed, one can use `transition` and simply toggle a class like this*

```js
var dom = {};
dom.creative = document.getElementById('creative');

var butt = document.getElementById('button');
butt.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
  dom.creative.classList.toggle('show');

})
```

```css
#creative {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  margin: 20px;
}
#creative.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
button {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Toggle display</button>

<div id="creative">
  <span>Sample text</span>
</div>
```

*For `transition`, besides the `offsetHeight` and the `setTimeout` solution, there is a 3:rd, having the same visual effect as toggle display block/none, setting the height/width to 0.*

```js
var dom = {};
dom.creative = document.getElementById('creative');

var butt = document.getElementById('button');
butt.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
  dom.creative.classList.toggle('show');

})
```

```css
#creative {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s, width 0s 1s;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
#creative.show {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s, width 0s;
}
button {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Toggle display</button>

<div id="creative">
  <span>Sample text</span>
</div>

<div>Other content</div>
```

Comment: @incompleteness Not needed ... or why you need that?

Comment: Because I do. Thank you.

Comment: @incompleteness Could you please explain why so I get the right facts for how to answer your question  properly

Comment: I don't know the real reason OP needs it, but I can imagine quite a few circumstances where you'd want `display:none`, for example if you don't want `.creative` to push down content after it until it fades in. Or what if `.creative` is actually an overlay? Just having it transparent the whole time won't be enough

Comment: The real reason I need it: setting the display property to block and some animated property to something else is a very common scenario that, as far I know, requires a extra useless (and forgettable) line of javascript code to work properly.

Comment: @incompleteness Updated my answer

Comment: That is it. You got it. Thank you. Sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: @incompleteness No need to be sorry :)

Comment: @LGSon now i'm just being curious, do you have any ideas about how to solve this using the transition instead of the animation?

Comment: @incompleteness They way you asked, to force a repaint... (because of the `display: none` ) ... without, just toggle a class on/off having `opacity: 1; transition: opacity 1s`

Comment: @incompleteness Updated my answer with a sample toggling a class

Comment: @LGSon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213118/workaround-for-display-block-and-css-transitions-work-properly

Answer (score 1):

There are no transitions defined for *absolute* properties, like *display*. How do you **interpolate** between `none` and `block`? You can't. But you can create some post-functions that will run after the animation is done.

### Using setTimeout

You can use `setTimeout` and execute some code *after* the animation is over:

```
ANIMATION_TIME = 0.5 * 1000; // in ms

function show(element) {
  // Display property must be set inmediatly; otherwise, the 'show' animation won't be visible until it ends.
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.opacity = 1;
}

function hide(element) {
  element.opacity = 0;

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  }, ANIMATION_TIME);
}

// Call examples
var dom = {};
dom.creative = document.getElementById('creative');
show(dom.creative);
hide(dom.creative);
```

### Using animation events

As @trustk has pointed out, you can also (and preferably) use DOM events:

```
function show(element) {
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.opacity = 1;
  element.removeEventListener("animationend", afterHide, false);
}

function afterHide(e) {
  // e.target -> element
  e.target.display = 'none';
}

function hide(element) {
  element.opacity = 0;
  element.addEventListener("animationend", afterHide, false);
}
```

Comment: But when you call `show()` the display will be none, so we won't see it?

Comment: @trusktr You're right. Probably, the `display` property should be set without timeout.

Comment: For sure. There's also animation events that are more accurate than a timeout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#Using_animation_events

Comment: You're welcome. :] Additionally, when you set `display = 'none'`, on the following line I think  you'd need `var a = element.offsetHeight` in order to repaint the element or the opacity transition won't work (that's what the issue OP was having, see his example). Haven't tested your code though.

Answer (score 0):

If you just add a timeout to the opacity call it should work! The duration can be almost nothing, as long as the display and opacity properties don't get called at the same time.

```
var dom = {};
dom.creative = document.getElementById('creative');
dom.creative.style.display = 'block';
setTimeout(function(){
  dom.creative.style.opacity = 1;
},1);
```

You can also use a jQuery fadein, if jQuery is an option. Then you can leave out the opacity altogether and just call it like...

```
dom.creative.fadeIn(500)
```

Comment: This may work, but it is so hacky and unintuitive. I wish browsers had some better way...

Comment: Just updated the answer - there's a jQuery function, fadeIn, that handles interpolating between none and block.

Comment: I'm not using jQuery and i don't think this solution is useful because, like trusktr said, it is unintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can show / hide element without javascript using css transition only.

```
<!--html-->
<div id="parent">Some parent text
    <div id="creative">Some details</div>
</div>

/*css*/
#parent #creative{
   opacity:0;
   visibility:hidden;
   clip: rect(0px,0px,0px,0px);
   transition: all 0.5s;
}
#parent:hover #creative{/*trigger transition*/
   opacity:1;
   visibility:visible;
   clip: rect(0px,220px,0px,330px);
}
```