# graphics animation with div class and sleep function update with javascript not done synchronously

Tags: javascript, html, css, graphics, redraw

I am trying to create a simple animation by `changing a div class` waiting a few millisecond before changing the next div class and so on.

The problem is that the graphics in my test browser ( Chrome ) are only refreshed at the end of all calls and not after each class change.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 9 ; i++ ){
       document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("class","blueSquare" );
       sleep(500);
    }
```

[here is the jsfiddle to test](http://jsfiddle.net/fxa76/1atr5jcp/4/)
I have tried various hacks presented in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac) but none seemed to work.
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to color the div at an interval one at a time. You can take a look at [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) which will apparently serve the purpose of *sleep*. `setTimeout` executes a function after certain period.

You also need to take a look at `closure` since `setTimeout` is asynchronous operation  but loop will not stop executing for setTimeout

```
var onClick = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++ ){
     (function(i){  // creating closure here
       setTimeout(function(){
         document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("class","blueSquare" );
       },i*500) // 1st div will be colored after 500 msec,second div 1000msec, & so on
     }(i))   
  }
};

$('#button').click(onClick);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1atr5jcp/6/)