# re-render HTML angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, refresh

I was wondering if it is at all possible re-render a specific element on a html page or the entire page itself whilst still keeping the controller the same.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `$scope.$apply()` from within your controller will re-render.

Comment: Hi,
What I have in the html is a widget that I update values from based on user input. $scope.$apply doesn't seem to refresh the widget.

Comment: @hahahakebab  What are you using to display the widget? Is it an iframe? JQuery?

Comment: Its a custom widget for an application I'm using. It acts similar to an iframe.

Comment: I think your answer may be to simply reload the DOM element

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac