# keyup function performing weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

So I got a little [codepen](https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/owYgMg). Everything works so far except a little thing. I got a `<h1>` and an `<input>`. When I type something in the text input, its value should get passed to the `<h1>` in realtime. 
I tried to do that with a **keyup** function:

```
$('input[name=titleInput]').keyup(function(){
  $('#title').text(this.value);
});
```

Something happens, but not what I want.
When I type something in the text input, then delete it (with backspace) and re-enter something, only the first character gets passed to the title.
Try it out on my codepen. Maybe it's just a stupid mistake of mine, but to me this behaviour is pretty weird.
Thanks for your help in advance!
**EDIT:**
I am using `text-fill-color`, which may causes the problem.
**EDIT 2:**
A friend of mine tested it. It worked for her. She's using Chrome and the same version as me (58.0.3029.110 (official build) (64-Bit)).

Comment: It seems to work perfectly on Firefox and has, indeed, a very weird behavior on Chrome. Do you see the same behaviors between the two browsers?

Comment: Can you try with .val(); instead of value

Comment: @atomrc I am currently working on my company's laptop and I haven't got Firefox. It works on Chrome on my smartphone tho.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I move the `title` id to another dom element, everything works well. So I guess it is a bug with Chrome and that specific text-fill you are using ?

Comment: @kanzari Already tried `.val()`. Getting an error `this.val is not a function`

Comment: @atomrc Yes, I thought that aswell. Pretty weird.

Comment: If I remove `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` then everything works as expected. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @atomrc Yes, it works without that property.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Can you just use the `color` property instead of `-webkit-text-fill-color`?

Comment: @R.McManaman Yes, I could. But the point of my codepen is that the title has the "inverted color of the background". And when I just use color, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Are you sure? Setting `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);` gets the exact same effect for me

Comment: @R.McManaman Well, that may be the case for some images. But try using like a black image. Then the title wouldn't be white with your code.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Fair enough, sorry!

Comment: @R.McManaman No problem! If I didn't find a solution, I would have used something like your suggestion. But I'm happy with t.niese's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome does not update the content correctly. Such kind of bugs can always happen if you use vendor prefixed css properties, so you should avoid those.

You could hide the container before update, and then show it again with a timeout. This will trigger an update, but would also result in flickering.

```
$('input[name=titleInput]').keyup(function(){
  $('.clipped').hide()
  $('#title').text(this.value);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.clipped').show();
  })
});
```

**EDIT** An alternative might be to use `background-clip` on the text and provide the inverted image yourself, but I right now don't have time to test that.

**EDIT2** Based on the test of @TobiasGlaus the following code does solve the problem without flickering:

```
$('input[name=titleInput]').keyup(function(){
  $('.clipped').hide().show(0)
  $('#title').text(this.value);
});
```

This seems to be different to `$('.clipped').hide().show()` most likely it starts an animation with duration `0` and uses `requestAnimationFrame` which also triggers a redraw. To not relay on this jQuery behaviour, the code should be written as:

```
$('input[name=titleInput]').keyup(function(){

  if( window.requestAnimationFrame ) {
    $('.clipped').hide();
  }

  $('#title').text(this.value);

  if( window.requestAnimationFrame ) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      $('.clipped').show();
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice solution! Works perfectly, but as you said it results in flickering. But I think I can live with that.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus you could try to experiment with some other css properties, like slightly toggling the zoom factor or the position using transformations, with a small factor like `0.1` on different elements, probably one of those would also result in a redraw

Comment: I tried out something else now. Instead of using a timeout, I just added this `$('.clipped').hide().show(0);` to my initial code. Not flickering anymore. Can you confirm that? (edited my codepen)

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Yes there is not flickering. I wouldn't have expected that. But maybe thats because jQuery starts an animation with a duration  `0`  that still uses `requestAnimationFrame` internally.

Comment: Yeah. (I have to commend Juank for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840703/5883638) tho.) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TobiasGlaus I would use `requestAnimationFrame` directly. I update my answer accordingly. Just to be sure that an update of jQuery won't break it.

Comment: Thanks alot. That's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

i'd use the following lines:

```
$('input[name=titleInput]').bind('keypress paste', function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
     var value = $('input[name=titleInput]').val();
     $('#title').text(value);
   }, 0)
});
```

This will listen to the paste / keypress events, and will update the value on change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's not working for me tho :/

Comment: @TobiasGlaus true, it does not trigger change on chrome, you will have to go with t.niese solution, to force redraw.