# Do function before confirm jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, confirm

here is my jquery code

```
$('.input').keyup(function(event){
    update_text(); // $('div').html('blahblah');
})
.blur(function(event){
    $(this).keyup();
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
        // do somthing...
    }
});
```

my problem is when input blur, confirm box should be show after doing update_text();

but update_text() seems run after confirm...

How to make it do update_text() first, then show confirm dialog?

Comment: Is it that `update_text()` runs after the `confirm()`, or that any changes `update_text()` makes to the page are not repainted until after the `confirm()`?

Comment: It seems `update_text` run before `confirm`. but `.html()` and `.val()` repaints after `confirm`. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your method does run before `confirm()`, the issue here is that your browser repaints the DOM asynchronously even though the method `.html()` is in itself synchronous. So while it doesn't appear to run first visually it indeed is.

For example a more simple version will have the same functionality, which can vary by browser:

```js
$("div").html("foo");
confirm('Are you sure?');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

One way to get around this is to [force the DOM to repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac) rather than letting the browser do it. For example:

```js
$("div").html("foo");
$("div").hide().show(function(){
  confirm('Are you sure?'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: *"your browser updates the DOM asynchronously"* - It updates the DOM synchronously, but does any resulting repaints asynchronously. (Just going for today's nitpicking award.) Anyway, you didn't suggest a solution - maybe use `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes sorry I meant repaints of the DOM.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek  That is what I'm facing on.Thanks for your explain :)

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm using setTimeout, and it working well. Thanks for your suggest. =D

Answer (score 0):

This might be too simple, but it seems like it fixes the problem.

```
$('.input').keyup(function(event){
  update_text(); // $('div').html('blahblah');
})
$('.input').blur(function(event){
  update_text();
  if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
    // do somthing...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`update_text()` happens on `keyup` event, which is triggered before the input is blurred, so if set up correctly it actually happens each time the user inputs another character.

```js
$('.input').keyup(function(event){
    update_text(); // $('div').html('blahblah');
})
.blur(function(event){
    $(this).keyup();
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
        // do somthing...
    }
});

update_text = function() {
  text = $('.input').val();
  $('#text').text(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='input'/>
<div id='text'>
```

Comment: It is just what I expected! Sadly it still not work on my code. :| Thanks for your help. :)