# Angular -- Safari not displaying DOM properly

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am new to Angular.

Using Angular 4, I try to update a specific element by setting the property in the associated component class file. However, the page is not updated unless I try to force a repaint of the webpage (by resizing window, etc). I opened the inspector and saw the DOM had been changed, but the display is clearly inconsistent with the HTML file in the element inspector.

The behavior occurred on Safari Version 11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.3) but not on Google Chrome.

I was able to resolve the problem by doing a force re-rendering as in [Force DOM redraw/refresh on Chrome/Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac). However, I suppose Safari should update the display in response to changes in DOM. Are there any ways to fix the problem other than doing a css redraw trick?

Comment: Did you find any more information? Are you using flexbox? How did you implement the suggestions in the linked issue? Iv'e attempted the same using animations to force a re-render but it seems an intermittent fix.