# Enable disabled checkbox and then click it with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to enable a checkbox and then click it via code. But it doesn't work. If I click the `enable and click checkbox` button the checkbox toggles. But if I press `disable checkbox` first it only gets enabled and not clicked by pressing `enable and click checkbox` button.

```js
function disableCheckbox() {
 $("#restprovider").prop("disabled", true);
}
function enableCheckboxAndClick() {
 $("#restprovider").prop("disabled", false);
  $("#restprovider").click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="restprovider" type="checkbox">
<button onclick="disableCheckbox()">
disable checkbox
</button>
<button onclick="enableCheckboxAndClick()">
enable and click checkbox
</button>
```

Comment: Works for me in Chrome

Comment: By click the checkbox do you mean you want to set it to checked? A click is not the best way to do that - you can just set it to checked

Comment: Working on Chrome 65.

Comment: And not in Firefox...so this is a browser issue

Comment: working in firefox too @LGSon

Comment: Well, not in mine, version 58.0.2

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It is truly a browser issue.

Comment: I can do this with `$("#restprovider").prop("checked", true/false);`, too. But that would not fire the onclick method from the checkbox

Comment: I just noticed your question edit. First: It is not only _older Firefox versions_ this happens to, I use their latest and it has the same issue. ... Second: Is it the `onclick` event you want to fire for the input or just toggle its checked status? ... Am asking, as if it's to really fire the event, the solution the accepted answer shows won't work either (seen here [https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/382/](https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/382/)), for the same reason I explained in my answer. If it is to set or toggle the state, then I updated my answer with a much simpler solution to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code (`$("#restprovider").click();`) works in Chrome but not in e.g. Firefox v.58.

The issue appears to be related to the fact that Firefox doesn't recognize the `checkbox` as enabled until after a *redraw* is made.

One option to fix that is to wrap the `click()` call in a `setTimeout()`, as shown in below sample, but there are several more options:

- [Force DOM redraw/refresh on Chrome/Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac)
- [How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes)

*Note, the here used timeout value of 4ms might not work cross browser, so its value might has to be adjusted a little.*

Stack snippet

```js
function disableCheckbox() {
  $("#restprovider").prop("disabled", true);
}

function enableCheckboxAndClick() {
  $("#restprovider").prop("disabled", false);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#restprovider").click();
  }, 4)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="restprovider" type="checkbox">
<button onclick="disableCheckbox()">
disable checkbox
</button>
<button onclick="enableCheckboxAndClick()">
enable and click checkbox
</button>
```

---

*Updated after a question edit*

If you are only interested e.g. in toggling the `input`'s checked state, simply do like this:

```js
function disableCheckbox() {
  $("#restprovider").prop("disabled", true);
}

function enableCheckboxAndClick() {
  $("#restprovider").prop("disabled", false);
  $("#restprovider").prop("checked", function() { this.checked = !this.checked });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="restprovider" type="checkbox">
<button onclick="disableCheckbox()">
disable checkbox
</button>
<button onclick="enableCheckboxAndClick()">
enable and click checkbox
</button>
```

Comment: This works for me with a little bigger timeout. Thanks!

Comment: @ochs.tobi You're welcome. I updated with a link that show some more ways to force a redraw.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
  $("#restprovider").click();
```

Use

```
 $("#restprovider").prop( "checked", true );
```

Now It won't toggle.

```js
function disableCheckbox() {
 $("#restprovider").prop("disabled", true);
}
function enableCheckboxAndClick() {
 $("#restprovider").prop("disabled", false);
  $("#restprovider").prop( "checked", true );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="restprovider" type="checkbox">
<button onclick="disableCheckbox()">
disable checkbox
</button>
<button onclick="enableCheckboxAndClick()">
enable and click checkbox
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use **checked** property instead:

```
var $restprovider = $('#restprovider');

function disableCheckbox() {
    $restprovider.prop("disabled", true);
}

function enableCheckboxAndClick() {  
    $restprovider.prop('disabled', false);
    $restprovider[0].checked 
        ? ($restprovider.click(), $restprovider.prop('checked', false)) 
        : $restprovider.prop('checked', true);
}
```

And here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/317/).

Answer (score -1):

your code works good.
you can resimple code with:

```
$("#restprovider").prop("disabled", false).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a checkbox that looks like it is disabled, you can do it like that:

```
$('#restprovider').css({pointerEvents:"none", opacity:0.5});
```