# CSS image size not render correctly

Tags: html, css, image

### First load

[image: CSS Image size wrong]

I set the width to 97px & height to 58px. But when it first load *(the elements created by jQuery)*, what I see in Chrome was 59.5px width.

### After uncheck the `width` checkbox, then re-check it

[image: CSS image size correct]

Now it display the correct size.

Is that the browser issue? How can I fix this?

- Google Chrome 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- macOS 10.14.5

Answer (score 0):

It is due to image size. If the size of the image is already how much you want then don't change the image size. When you give the same size browser tries to override and then problem occurs(which is wrong image size).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! 
If you want to give a single user some feedback, post it as a comment. Answers are for all users on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving important in CSS
like and use any parent div that is static or whose class name you know

```
div > img{
  width: 97px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack to solve. [Force DOM redraw/refresh on Chrome/Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac/8840580#8840580)

After the content loaded

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.parent img').hide().show(0);
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by preloading the image. I placed the following within the  tag of my page:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="path/to/image.png" as="image">
```